# Centering Row of Images in Mailchimp Custom HTML

Tags: html, html-email, mailchimp

Here is a snippet of code I used to create a block of images. I want these to be centered in the email container. The preview on Mailchimp is showing correctly, but once I send the test to myself, all of the images are aligned to the left of the container, not centered.

Here is the code:

```
<style>
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 0 px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    max-width: 125px;

}
</style>
<div class="row" vertical-align="middle" align="center">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
        <img src="">
    </div>  
</div>
   <!--- BOTTOM ROW -->
<div class="row" vertical-align="middle" align="center">
    <div class="column">
                <img src="">
<img src="">
 
    </div>  
</div>
```

I've tried playing with the vertical-align properties, adding 'display: block;' and 'margin: 0 auto;' to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. With emails, its best to forget how to do coding. Start with **tables** and **inline CSS**, `div`'s can be used but support is minimal. Go old school coding.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is sad and simple: E-Mail clients still work very differently from browsers. The CSS you are trying to apply is most likely just being ignored by your E-Mail client.

As you can see on https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex-wrap flex-wrap is very poorly supported by E-Mail clients. Very useful resource to find out whats supported and whats not.

To center content, it is recommended to use tables instead of divs, they are supported by most E-Mail clients.

```html
<table style="margin:auto;max-width:500px;background-color:red;color:white;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Centered Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```